# Best practices for testing a golang's Web apps query parameters

Tags: testing, go

In a simple case of two required parameters, there are four possible test cases IIUC:

1. both empty
2. first set but not second
3. second set but not first
4. both set

What is best practice, test all four cases?

Because even testing the first and last cases is quite verbose in Golang:

```
func TestGoodParameter(t *testing.T) {

        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)

        q := req.URL.Query()
        q.Add("first", "foo")
        q.Add("second", "bar")
        req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

        rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
        root(rec, req)
        res := rec.Result()

        if res.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
                t.Errorf("got %v, expected %v", res.StatusCode, http.StatusOK)
        }

}

func TestBadParameter(t *testing.T) {

        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)

        rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
        root(rec, req)
        res := rec.Result()

        if res.StatusCode != http.StatusBadRequest {
                t.Errorf("got %v, expected %v", res.StatusCode, http.StatusBadRequest)
        }

}
```

Or are there some tricks I am missing here? It obviously gets even more complicated when say there are five parameters where two of them are optional!

Comment: Use [table driven tests](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests) to fight the verbosity.

Comment: General rule. When in doubt about best practices: Take a look at how the stdlib solves the problem.

Comment: @volker stdlib doesn't test Web apps, now does it ?

Comment: Well, if you insist that "test Web apps" is _so_ _much_ different than testing a HTTP endpoint: Yes. Otherwise no. Please take a look. And: How to test your "Web app" from a testing-technical point is nothing special. As Cerise recommended use table driven tests.

Comment: root func doesn't exists

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define your test cases table driven way and write a single implementation for it. You can simplify definition by omitting the name of test cases.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestParameters(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := map[string]struct {
        params map[string]string
        statusCode int
    }{
        "good params": {
            map[string]string{
                "first": "foo", "second": "bar",
            },
            http.StatusOK,
        },
        "without params": {
            map[string]string{},
            http.StatusBadRequest,
        },
    }

    for tc, tp := range testCases {
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
        q := req.URL.Query()
        for k, v := range tp.params {
            q.Add(k, v)
        }
        req.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()
        rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
        root(rec, req)
        res := rec.Result()
        if res.StatusCode != tp.statusCode {
            t.Errorf("`%v` failed, got %v, expected %v", tc, res.StatusCode, tp.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```